# Reconstruct boundaries and compute length in Paraview

Tags: gradient, paraview

I have a set of points on the unit sphere and a corresponding set of values being equal, for simplicity, to 0 and 1. Thus I'm constructing the characteristic function of a set on the sphere. Typically, I have several such sets, which form a partition of the sphere. An example is given in the figure.

[image]

> I was wondering if paraview can find boundaries between the cells and compute the length and the curvature of the boundaries.

I read in a paper that using gradient reconstruction the guys managed to find the curvature of such contours. I imagine that if the curvature can be found, the length should be somewhat simpler. If the answer to the above question is yes, where should I look for the corresponding documentation?

Comment: mmm... I would guess curvature of curve on the sphere is 1/R. In case curve center is at (0,0,0) for unit sphere curvature is 1. For non-cocentric curve you build chord plane and find it's center and radius, 1/r would be curvature

Comment: What do you have for point coordinates? Angles?

Comment: For point coordinates I have actual x, y, z values. Concerning your first comment, these partitions are generated by a program and although it is suspected they are arcs of circles, I would like to be able to verify this by finding the curves and computing their curvatures.

Comment: ok, let me write some answer and see if it is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

For points on the sphere if they are build based on great-circle distance principle, it means all lines connecting points are of a shortest distance and plane goes through sphere center. In such case angle could be computed as arccos of scalar product.

```
R = 1;
angle  = arccos(x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2);
length = R*angle;
```

And parametric line from p1 to p2 could be build using slerp interpolation.

```
slerp(t) = sin((1.0-t)*angle)/sin(angle)*p1 + sin(t*angle)/sin(angle)*p2;
```

where `t` is in [0...1] range

In such case curvature is 1/R for all great circle lines. That would be first thing I would try - try to match actual boundaries with those made from great-circle approach. If they match, that's the answer

Links

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

UPDATE

In case of non-great arcs I would propose following modification. Build great arc plane which goes through sphere center and on intersection with surface makes great arc between the points. Fix axis as a line going through those two points. Start rotating great arc plane along above mentioned axis till you get the exactly your arc of circle connecting two points. At this moment you could get rotation angle, compute your circle plane position and radius `r`, curvature as `1/r` etc

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but this is not what I am after. I know that the curves connecting the points are arcs of circles, but they are not geodesics (great arcs).